# CSS3 or CSS 3, HTML5 or HTML 5: what should we use in question titles and body?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Which is better for search and accuracy?

- `CSS3` or `CSS 3`
- `HTML5` or `HTML 5`

What should we use in question titles and content?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I feel a strong need to say this: **not every HTML5 question is a CSS3 question, and not every CSS3 question is an HTML5 question. They are separate technologies.** Don't use both tags in the same question if it's only related to one or the other.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter: We will never get people to stick to one standard anyway.

This is where tagging comes in. There, there exists a standard: [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) and [html5](/questions/tagged/html5). It's enforced by the system - there can't be a tag named `css 3` or `html 5`.

Comment: I know the tag are without spaces. Is it good to follow that pattern in question's title too?

Comment: @Jitendra I don't think it matters. If you want to do it correctly, you can stick to the standards Bobby shows, but there will be thousands of people who never will. This is a searchability issue that will have to be addressed by the search engine (as there will be people writing questions *and* searching for both `css3` and `css 3`)

Comment: ok which method u would prefer? :-)

Comment: @Jitendra in question titles and bodies, I personally tend to use "CSS 3" and "HTML 5", like when I would speak it. Feels most natural to me.

Comment: How CSS3 and "CSS 3" are different in speaking. Will u give a pause after CSS to speak "CSS 3" ?

Comment: @Jitendra I think there would be a *slight* pause in some constellations. But it's admittedly not a big difference now that I think about it.

Comment: There could be tags named `css-3` and `html-5` though, and there doesn't seem to be any universal convention of whether tags should be named `fooversion` or `foo-version`.

Comment: @Pekka: Constellations...?

Comment: @BoltClock "I love CSS 3 over CSS 2". <--- Pause  "But when we look at CSS 3, we see that" <--- slightly shorter pause (It doesn't have to be a universal rule, though - didn't think this through much)

Answer (score 2):

The correct names:

- [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)
- [CSS3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS#CSS3)

Well, to be honest, I can't find an reference to an official name of CSS3, because [it seems to be splitted](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs).

Comment: The official name for CSS3 is really CSS level 3. And even then, it's all modularized. But +1 for HTML5 being the official name, because who knows, this may actually convince *somebody* that yes, it *is* officially named without a space.